# How to make 2 forms in one view dealing with the same entity but with only one bind to it?

Tags: php, symfony

Here is the thing.

I want to make 2 forms in one view. One is bound to an entity and the other is a file type where I want to put .csv and catch the informations inside to fill the first entity.

I've already created the first one but I can't figure how to create the second and integrate it correctly in the same view so they don't fight each other. Here is my files (the csv process is not here yet)

My controller:

```
public function adminAction()
    {
    $form = $this->createForm(new StudentsType, null);
    $formHandler = new StudentsHandler($form, $this->get('request'), $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager());

    if( $formHandler->process() )
    {
        return $this->redirect( $this->generateUrl('EnsgtiEnsgtiBundle_ens'));
    }

    return $this->render('EnsgtiEnsgtiBundle:Appli:admin.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));

    }
```

First form:

```
class StudentsType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('nom', 'text')->setRequired(false)
            ->add('prenom', 'text')
            ->add('email', 'email')
            ->add('codeEtape', 'text')
            ->add('file', new StudentsListType)->SetRequired(false);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'ensgti_ensgtibundle_studentstype';
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'Ensgti\EnsgtiBundle\Entity\Students',
        );
    }

}
```

The Handler:

```
class StudentsHandler
{
    protected $form;
    protected $request;
    protected $em;

    public function __construct(Form $form, Request $request, EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->form    = $form;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->em      = $em;
    }

    public function process()
    {
        if( $this->request->getMethod() == 'POST' )
        {
            $this->form->bindRequest($this->request);

            if( $this->form->isValid() )
            {
                $this->onSuccess($this->form->getData());

                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function onSuccess(Students $students)
    {
        $this->em->persist($students);
        $this->em->flush();
    }
}
```

Second Form:

```
class StudentsListType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('', 'file');

    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'ensgti_ensgtibundle_studentslisttype';
    }

}
```

The Handler:

```
class StudentsListHandler
{
    protected $form;
    protected $request;
    protected $em;

    public function __construct(Form $form, Request $request, EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->form    = $form;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->em      = $em;
    }

    public function process()
    {
        if( $this->request->getMethod() == 'POST' )
        {
            $this->form->bindRequest($this->request);

            if( $this->form->isValid() )
            {
                //$this->onSuccess($this->form->getData());
                print_r($this->form->getData());
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function onSuccess(/*StudentsList $studentsList*/)
    {
        //$this->em->persist($studentsList);
        //$this->em->flush();
        echo 'Petit test';
    }
}
```

With this code I get this:

> Neither property "file" nor method "getFile()" nor method "isFile()" exists in class "Ensgti\EnsgtiBundle\Entity\Students"

Which is normal since I'm bind to an entity with no file type. I'm a beginner so I keep reading docs but it's still hard for me to understand everything. Is there a way I can make 2 forms in the same view with one that is not bind to an entity but that will persist on it anyway via csv treatment??

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the form expects `file` to be a property of the bound entity. You just need to set the `property_path` to false. ([Reference](http://www.richsage.co.uk/2011/07/20/adding-non-entity-fields-to-your-symfony2-forms/)) e.g.

```
->add('file', new StudentsListType, array('property_path' => false))
```

**Edit:**

If it would make more sense to have the 2 forms completely separate, then remove the above `->add(/*...*/)` entirely and just pass both forms to the view from the controller. You can then render each one individually.

Comment: This one doesn't work. The thing is, when I'm filling the first form field the second one is required on submit. And when I do this: ->add('file', new StudentsListType, array('property_path' => false))->setRequired(false); nothing is persisted in my entity.

Answer (score -3):

use `<iframe>` to do that. Here is the [link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) how to use it, just put in `src` atribute url to needed page. And you may display 2 pages in one layout. And this is how it  [looks](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp)

Comment: I'm sure there's a way to do what I want without Iframe, I really want to understand how Symfony works.